# JPA - Is there a way to select based on a priority

Tags: java, jpa

I have an object called Configuration that looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONFIGURATION")
public class Configuration {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "SERVICE")
    private String service;

    @Column(name = "KEY")
    private String key;

    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private String value;
}
```

There is a composite unique constraint on service and key.

We have a jpa repository for the above model:

```
public interface ConfigurationRepository extends JpaRepository<Configuration, Long>{

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
    @Query("SELECT c FROM Configuration c WHERE c.service=:service AND c.key=:key)
    Configuration findConfigurationByServiceAndKey(@Param("service") String service, @Param("key") String key);
}
```

A user is able to define their own service, and if no config is found for the given service, we always look again for the default key. So we always do the following:

```
public Configuration getConfiguration(String service, String key) {
    Configuration config = configurationRepository.findConfigurationByServiceAndKey(service, key);
    if (config == null) {
         config = configurationRepository.findConfigurationByServiceAndKey("DEFAULT", key);
    }
    return config;
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do this in one query? It's not as simple as doing a `SELECT c FROM Configuration c WHERE (c.service=:service OR c.service=:'DEFAULT') AND c.key=:key`, as this would return multiple configs if they existed. The logic I want is if a config with the given key exists for the given service, return it. Otherwise, return the one for 'DEFAULT. Does anybody know if this is possible in one query?

Comment: Why not simply execute the query that returns both, and return the most specific one from the repository or service method?

Comment: @JBNizet That was going to be the approach I was going to take if I can't find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can: indicate default value using additional boolean column, select rows matching either service or default value, order result to have row with default value at the end E.g.

```
SELECT c FROM Configuration c WHERE (c.service=:service OR c.isDefault = true) AND c.key=:key ORDER BY c.isDefault DESC
```

Unfortunately you cannot set limit in the query, so repository should return a List. First item is the one you want.